# Поиск и замена строки со временем в формате с секундами и без

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

Передо мной стоит следующая задача:

> Вовочка подготовил одно очень важное письмо, но везде указал
>   неправильное время.  Поэтому нужно заменить все вхождения времени на
>   строку (TBD). Время — это строка вида HH:MM:SS или HH:MM, в которой HH
>   — число от 00 до 23, а MM и SS — число от 00 до 59.
>
> Ввод: Уважаемые!
>   Если вы к 09:00 не вернёте  чемодан, то уже в 09:00:01 я за себя не
>   отвечаю.  PS. С отношением 25:50 всё нормально!
>
> Вывод: Уважаемые! Если вы к (TBD) не вернёте  чемодан, то уже в (TBD) я
>   за себя не отвечаю.  PS. С отношением 25:50 всё нормально!

Я решаю ее следующим образом:

```
import re

newStr = 'Уважаемые! Если вы к 09:00 не вернете чемодан.\n\
То уже в 09:00:01 я за себя не отвечаю!\n\
PS Со времнем 25:50 все нормально.'
print(newStr)
s = re.findall(\
  '(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d)'
  ,newStr)

print(s)
```

Как правильно построить регулярное выражение, чтобы оно захватывало, либо `HH:MM:SS`, либо `HH:MM`, а не только `HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: `(?:[01]\d|2[0123])(:(?:[012345]\d)){1,2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [269]: pat = r'((?:[01]\d|2[0-3])\:(?:[0-5]\d)(?:\:[0-5]\d)?)'

In [270]: res = re.sub(pat, "(TBD)", newStr)

In [271]: print(res)
Уважаемые! Если вы к (TBD) не вернете чемодан.
То уже в (TBD) я за себя не отвечаю!
PS Со времнем 25:50 все нормально.
```

---

```
In [272]: re.findall(pat, newStr)
Out[272]: ['09:00', '09:00:01']
```